# ASP.Net 5 RC1 unresolved dependency: NU1001 The dependency ... >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json

I hoping someone can help shed some light on how to get around this issue. I've noticed this issue while attempting to add a classic .csproj class library to a ASP.NET 5 RC1 xproj project and while attempting to add references to regualar .NET 4.5-4.6 assemblies to xproj based ASP.NET 5 RC1 projects. In this particular case I'm trying to add a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime to an ASP.NET 5 WebApi project. I can see a wrap file get's generated that looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": {
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../lib/dnx46/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The reference in the project.json file looks like this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },
```

When open up the project.lock.json file I see the following get added:

```
"DNX,Version=v4.6": [
  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime >= 1.0.0-*"
]
```

When I look at the references in visual studio I see the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there any kind of workaround for this issue?

Comment: I run into same issue, did you manage to figure out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as  "a problem that can no longer be reproduced"